# Get all phonebookdata from android phone

Tags: android, optimization, query-optimization

I am not really experienced with App development but I have to write an App that reads all phonebookdata and saves it to a xml file.

My current version is running on my phone (with just 150 contacts). But when I run it on a device with several thousand contacts the app gets really slow. When I click on a button it takes nearly one minute until the new screen is shown.

I guess the structure of my app is not really good. That's how I currently read all the data:

private void xmlPart2(XmlSerializer serializer) {

```
try {

  ContentResolver contentr = getContentResolver();
  Cursor cursor = contentr.query(
      ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

  if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

      String id = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

      serializer.startTag(null, "Contact");
      serializer.attribute(null, "ID", id);



      Cursor emailCur = contentr.query(
          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
          null,
          ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID
              + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

      serializer.startTag(null, "Emails");

      while (emailCur.moveToNext()) {

        String email = emailCur
            .getString(emailCur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));

        String emailtype = emailCur
            .getString(emailCur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE));

        this.appendNode(serializer, "Email", email, emailtype);
      }

      serializer.endTag(null, "Emails");
      emailCur.close();




      if (Integer
          .parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor
              .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

        Cursor pCur = contentr
            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                    + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                null);

        serializer.startTag(null, "Numbers");

        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {

          String phonenumber = pCur
              .getString(pCur
                  .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          String phonetype = pCur
              .getString(pCur
                  .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE));

          this.appendNode(serializer, "Number", phonenumber,
              phonetype);
        }

        serializer.endTag(null, "Numbers");

        pCur.close();

      }

      serializer.endTag(null, "Contact");
    }
  }

  cursor.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

This is just one part of the code. In the current code I read following fields:
Name, Address, Email, Organization, Notes, Instant Messengers, Websites, Nickname and Phone Numbers.

Is there a way to optimize it? As it should also work below API level 11, I can not use the CursorLoader.

I am thankful for every suggestion.

Comment: is this piece of code running in the main thread?

Answer (score 1):

Please run the contact reading code in an new Thread. then call the loading alert (progress bar). After contact fetching call the handler to hide tha loding alert and use bundle to pass the data to your next screen.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and maybe you would like to show progresses to the user using [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Comment: I was just using the AsyncTask to send the data to the server. Now I also put the whole reading code in the AsyncTask and it's running without problems. Thanks!!